# Factors deciding the number of bytes read from the InputStream

Tags: networking, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bytearrayoutputstream

The processing of writing data in the ByteArrayOutputStream from InputStream obtained by urlConnection.getInputStream() is taking more than 1 minute.

**CODE** **SNIPPET**

```
URL requestUrl= new URL(_sampleurl_);  
HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)requestUrl.openConnection();  
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);  
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");  
urlConnection.connect();  
int statusCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();   //200  
long contentLengthByTen = urlConnection.getHeaderFieldLong("Content-Length", _defaultSize_); //7631029  
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();  
final byte[] byteArray = new byte[16384];  
int length;  
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrOutStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
int k = 0;  
while ((length = inputStream.read(byteArray)) != -1)  
{  
    byteArrOutStrm.write(byteArray, 0, length);  
    k++;  
}
```

Some of the observations are:
The while loop alone executing for more than one minute and it is iterated for around 2650 times.
The HttpURLConnection response code is 200, so the entire content is available in the InputStream.
The Content-Length of the file is 7631029 (bytes).

I have two questions:

1. Though the byte array size is 16384 and the status code is 200, the inputStream.read method reads only 2800 bytes averagely. Why and which factors decide these bytes?
2. Proper solution to reduce the processing time?

Comment: "The HttpURLConnection response code is 200, so the entire content is available in the InputStream." That doesn't mean the entire content *has already been sent*.

Comment: And it therefore also doesn't mean that the entire content is now available in the socket receive buffer to be read in a single read. There is still I/O and flushing and segmentation and packetizing at the sender, and packet losses and retransmissions in the network.

Comment: Yeah. I misunderstood that 200 status code indicates successful completion of request, which actually indicates that the request is success(OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Though the byte array size is 16384 and the status code is 200, the inputStream.read method reads only 2800 bytes averagely. Why and which factors decide these bytes?

The number of bytes available in the socket receive buffer, which in turn is a function of the speed of the sender, the frequency of reads at the receiver, the network bandwidth, and the path MTU. What you're seen isn't surprising: it indicates that you're keeping up with the sender pretty well.

> 2. Proper solution to reduce the processing time?

Have the sender send faster. There is nothing wrong with your receiving code, although I wonder why you're collecting the entire response in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` before doing anything with it. This just wastes memory and adds latency.

Comment: Thank you EJP. It is noted that the problem is due to the delay of response data from the sender.
FYI, The _sampleurl_ is the audio url given by the user and it's binary content is written in ByteArrayOutputStream which is then converted to byte array for further audio processing.